# Possible to call STORE on deeper level tied hash assignment?

Tags: perl, tie

I'm trying to write a Perl module for a “persistent YAML hash”, with the following properties:

- With every access, check if the YAML file has changed, and if so, reload.
- As soon as any data in the hash is changed, save.
- *Don't* save on `UNTIE`, so that the file isn't updated when you only read values.

My first attempt seemed to work pretty well:

```
package YAMLHash;

use v5.24;
use warnings;
use experimental 'signatures';

use YAML::XS qw(DumpFile LoadFile);
use File::stat;

sub refresh($self)
{
    if (-f $self->{file}) {
        if (stat($self->{file})->mtime > $self->{mtime}) {
            $self->{data} = LoadFile($self->{file});
            $self->{mtime} = stat($self->{file})->mtime;
        }
    }
}

sub save($self)
{
    DumpFile($self->{file}, $self->{data});
    $self->{mtime} = stat($self->{file})->mtime;
}

sub TIEHASH($class, @args)
{
    my ($filename) = $args[0];
    die "No filename specified" unless $filename;
    my $self = bless { data=>{}, file=>$filename, mtime=>0 }, $class;
    refresh($self);
    return $self;
}

sub FETCH($self, $key = '')
{
    refresh($self);
    return $self->{data}{$key};
}

sub EXISTS($self, $key)
{
    refresh($self);
    return exists($self->{data}{$key});
}

sub FIRSTKEY($self)
{
    refresh($self);
    my @ignore = keys %{$self->{data}}; # reset iterator
    return each %{$self->{data}};
}

sub NEXTKEY($self, $lastkey)
{
    refresh($self);
    return each %{$self->{data}};
}

sub SCALAR($self)
{
    return scalar %{$self->{data}};
}

sub STORE($self, $key, $value)
{
    refresh($self);
    $self->{data}{$key} = $value;
    save($self);
}

sub DELETE($self, $key)
{
    refresh($self);
    delete $self->{data}{$key};
    save($self);
}

sub CLEAR($self, $key)
{
    $self->{data} = {};
    save($self);
}

1;
```

I tried this as follows:

```
use YAMLHash;

tie my %foo, 'YAMLHash', 'test.yaml';

$foo{hello} = 'world';
$foo{answer} = 42;
$foo{counter}++;
```

and the resulting YAML file looks like this:

```
---
answer: 42
counter: 1
hello: world
```

But then I changed my example code to:

```
use YAMLHash;

tie my %foo, 'YAMLHash', 'test.yaml';

$foo{hello} = 'world';
$foo{answer} = 42;
$foo{counter}++;
$foo{a}{b}{c}{d} = 'e';
```

and the result is:

```
---
a: {}
answer: 42
counter: 2
hello: world
```

So, obviously, `STORE` is called when `$foo{a}` is created, but not when `$foo{a}{b}{c}{d}` is assigned.

Is there any way to make this do what I want?

Comment: Maybe you could do it if `FETCH()` returned a tied hash of `YAMLHash` instead of a simple reference (I was not able to make it work though). Also I have not looked into the XS api, it might be possible from XS..

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I guess you need to check in both `FETCH` and `STORE` to see if a hash reference is assigned, and if so, return/assign a tied hash.  Of course, for completeness, you'd need to do something similar with array references.  This might work, but makes it a whole lot more complex, of course.

Comment: Take look at [DBM::Deep](http://metacpan.org/pod/DBM::Deep), which does something like what you want. The only difference is that the file isn't YAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to tie `%{ $foo{a} }`, `%{ $foo{a}{b} }` and `%{ $foo{a}{b}{c} }` as well.

You could recursively tie the hashes and arrays in the data structure in `TIEHASH`. Don't forget to the do the same thing to data added to the structure via `STORE`!

You might want to use a different class for the root of the data structure and non-root nodes.

Warning: Using `tie` will make accesses slower.

---

Note that you need to tie the scalars too, not just the hashes (and arrays). All of the following change the value of a hash element without calling `STORE`:

- Changing the scalar directly:

  - `++$foo{a};`
  - `chomp($foo{a});`
  - `$foo{a} =~ s/x/y/g;`
  - ...
- Changing a scalar via an alias or a reference:

  - `my \$x = \$foo{a}; $x = 123;`
  - `my $r = \$foo{a}; $$r = 123;`
  - `for ($foo{a}) { $_ = 123; }`
  - `sub { $_[0] = 123; }->($foo{a});`
  - ...